# How can I find all files that are not of a certain kind using Spotlight?

Tags: macos, search, find, spotlight

I can enter "Shockwave Flash Movie" in the the search field of a Finder window and find all files that are of Kind, "Shockwave Flash Movie"  However, I really want a list of all files that are NOT Shockwave Flash Movie.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways:

One is, select `Kind`, `Other` and enter

`-"Shockwave Flash Movie"`

However, this will also filter out all other types whose names only *contain* with "Shockwave Flash Movie". The chance is low, fortunately.

---

The other way is performing a raw spotlight query by selecting the entry `Raw Query` from the first menu.

Then you can enter the following:

`kMDItemContentType != "public.jpeg"`

This finds all files except JPEG images. `"public.jpeg"` of course is the file type you want to exclude.

To find out the internal name of SWF files, open a `Terminal.app` window, type `mdls` (with trailing Space) and drag&drop an .SWF file into this terminal window. Press Enter. Now look for a line starting with `kMDItemContentType`, this is the name of the SWF file type you must enter into the search query. (You only have to do this part once.)

Comment: Interesting, -"Shockwave Flash Movie" doesn't work for me, but you other way is working.  Plus, I feel it is more powerful.  Thank you.

Comment: @Michael: It depends on what the file type is called on your system. Open a directory in list view and look in the "Kind" column. This is what you need to enter.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried: -"Plain text" and I got tons of file except those of the Plain text kind
Hope this helps